# How to access newly opened small tab in the current tab using selenium web driver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I clicked on sign in button from the below link and it is opened a small tab inside the same window. i want to access the current small tab and fill information. url:https://www.tajawal.ae/en Kindly suggest how i can do this using python selenium webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the URL which you shared, the small tab/web popup neither appears in new frame nor in new window, so you don't need to do frame/window switch. you can simply access popup elements

In-case, if you had tried to interact with 'email' input box in the small pop up and if it has not worked, please see my answer below.

**You have 2 email inputs boxes with the same name(attribute name) - "email", one in popup, another one in the same page under subscribe to newsletter section.** If you had tried to enter something in popup's **email** input box, it would have entered in the newsletter section. **So to enter correctly in popup's email input box , use xpath --> (//input[@name='email'])[2]**

Answer (score 0):

To send a character sequence to the *Email* and *Password*  field within the website https://www.tajawal.com/en you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.tajawal.com/en")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-testid='Header__SignInButton']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='Email']//following::input[@name='email']"))).send_keys("paul@paul.paul")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='Password']//following::input[@name='password']").send_keys("paul@paul.paul")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: tajawal]